# Select greatest 1 per group using EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, arcgis, exists

I have a RoadInsp table in Oracle 18c. I've put the data in a CTE for purpose of this question:

```
with roadinsp (objectid, asset_id, date_) as (
select  1, 1, to_date('2016-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select  2, 1, to_date('2019-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select  3, 1, to_date('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select  4, 2, to_date('2016-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select  5, 2, to_date('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select  6, 3, to_date('2022-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select  7, 3, to_date('2016-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select  8, 3, to_date('2018-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select  9, 3, to_date('2013-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
select 10, 3, to_date('2010-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
)
select * from roadinsp
```

```
  OBJECTID   ASSET_ID DATE_     
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 2016-04-01
         2          1 2019-03-01
         3          1 2022-01-01 --select this row

         4          2 2016-04-01
         5          2 2021-01-01 --select this row

         6          3 2022-03-01 --select this row
         7          3 2016-04-01
         8          3 2018-03-01
         9          3 2013-03-01
        10          3 2010-06-01
```

I'm using GIS software that only lets me use SQL in a WHERE clause/SQL expression, not a full SELECT query.

I want to select the greatest 1 per group using the WHERE clause. In other words, for each ASSET_ID, I want to select the row that has the latest date.

---

As an experiment, I want to make the selection specifically using the EXISTS operator.

The reason being: While this post technically pertains to Oracle (since that's what S.O. community members would have access to), in practice, I want to use the logic in a proprietary database called a *file geodatabase*. The file geodatabase has very limited SQL support; a small subset of SQL-92 syntax. But it does seem to support EXISTS and subqueries, although not correlated subqueries. *Very frustrating.*

> [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm)
>
> Subquery support in file geodatabases is limited to the following:
>
> - Scalar subqueries with comparison operators. A scalar subquery returns a single value, for example:
>
>   `GDP2006 > (SELECT MAX(GDP2005) FROM countries)`
>
>   For file geodatabases, the set functions AVG, COUNT, MIN, MAX, and
>   SUM can only be used in scalar subqueries.
> - EXISTS predicate, for example:
>
>   `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM indep_countries WHERE COUNTRY_NAME = 'Mexico')`

---

**Question:**

Using the EXISTS operator, is there a way to select the greatest 1 per group? (keeping in mind the limitations mentioned above)

**Edit:**

If an asset has multiple rows with the same top date, then only one of those rows should be selected (arbitrarily).

Comment: NOT EXISTS could do the job, but its subquery should be correlated.

Comment: Like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/nvvbaCyj

Comment: Or using scalar subquery which returns the last date per asset: `where date_ = (select max(subq.date_) from RoadInsp subq where RoadInsp.asset_id = subq.asset_id)`

Comment: @astentx Can you confirm that's a scalar subquery? To my untrained eye, that looks like a correlated subquery. Unfortunately, correlated subqueries aren't supported in the proprietary "File Geodatabase" that I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

`rank` analytic function does the job, if it is available to you (Oracle 18c certainly does support it).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with roadinsp (objectid, asset_id, date_) as (
  2  select  1, 1, to_date('2016-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  3  select  2, 1, to_date('2019-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  4  select  3, 1, to_date('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  5  select  4, 2, to_date('2016-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  6  select  5, 2, to_date('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  7  select  6, 3, to_date('2022-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  8  select  7, 3, to_date('2016-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  9  select  8, 3, to_date('2018-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
 10  select  9, 3, to_date('2013-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
 11  select 10, 3, to_date('2010-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
 12  ),
```

Query begins here: first rank rows per `asset_id` by date in descending order:

```
 13  temp as
 14    (select r.*,
 15       rank() over (partition by asset_id order by date_ desc) rnk
 16     from roadinsp r
 17    )
```

Finally, fetch rows that rank as the highest:

```
 18  select *
 19  from temp
 20  where rnk = 1;

  OBJECTID   ASSET_ID DATE_             RNK
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3          1 2022-01-01          1
         5          2 2021-01-01          1
         6          3 2022-03-01          1

SQL>
```

---

If you can't use that, how about a subquery?

```
<snip>
 13  select r.objectid, r.asset_id, r.date_
 14  from roadinsp r
 15  where (r.asset_id, r.date_) in (select t.asset_id, t.max_date
 16                                  from (select a.asset_id, max(a.date_) max_date
 17                                        from roadinsp a
 18                                        group by a.asset_id
 19                                       ) t
 20                                 );

  OBJECTID   ASSET_ID DATE_
---------- ---------- ----------
         6          3 2022-03-01
         5          2 2021-01-01
         3          1 2022-01-01

SQL>
```